# why i cant print aa in b function using python

Tags: python, scope

this is my code :

```
def a():
    print aa

def b():
    aa = 'aaaa'
    a()

b()
```

it show error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g.py", line 12, in <module>
    b()
  File "g.py", line 10, in b
    a()
  File "g.py", line 6, in a
    print aa
NameError: global name 'aa' is not defined
```

the `aa` must be defined in the b function,

what can i do ,

thanks

Comment: Why do you think this should work? I have not encountered a language so far where this would work (but I still have some to learn ;)).

Comment: @Felix: There's dynamic scoping, which is all about this behaviour. But it speaks volumes about its pros and cons that it's almost extinct now (I only know Perl and Emacs Lisp, and the former allows both) and was abandoned by several languages that used to have it.

Comment: @delnan: I see. Thank you. As I said, I don't know every language and those I know don't have this behaviour. If their would have been some more explanation like *In Perl I can do this and this, but it does not seem to work in Python* then it would have made more sense to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

aa is only defined in the scope of b(). You can pull the variable definition out of the function or use it as an argument.

This should work:

```
def a():
    print aa

def b():
    global aa
    aa = 'aaaa'
    a()

b()
```

This should also work, of course:

```
def a(aa):
    print aa

def b():
    aa = 'aaaa'
    a(aa)

b()
```

Comment: -1: Did you actually test it? It doesn't work. (hint. missing "global aa")

Comment: indeed. I thought the global definition of the variable would be visible in the function scope without the use of global.

Comment: @jm_toball: Only if you not change the variable in the function.

Answer (score 2):

`aa = 'aaaa'` is local only to b() as a function. To print this inside a() you need to ether return it into a() like this

```
def a(arg):
    print arg

def b():
    aa = 'test'
    return a(aa)
```

Or (and this is the WORST way to do it. You should never do it this way, im only showing it as an explanation)

```
def b():
    global aa
    aa = 'test'
    a()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def a():
    global aa
    print aa

def b():
    global aa
    aa = 'aaaa'
    a()

b()
```

One solution, but is better to pass `aa` as argument to `a()`

Comment: So you basically copied my second example but without explaining its a BAD idea.

Comment: I guess he must be really fast at copying then. I think we just all had the same ideas. So it's +1 for all

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using better names for your functions and variables - a(), b() are kind of meaningless.
To get your code to work, you'll have to either make aa a global variable (not recommended) or pass it to the a function:

```
def a(aa):
    print aa  

def b():
    aa = 'aaaa'
    a(aa)

b()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
aa = None

def a():
    print aa

def b():
    global aa
    aa = 'aaaa'
    a()

b()
```